Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range в Python при сравнении двух элементов из разных списков
a = [2, 13, -4, 5, -6, 3, -2, 8, 14]
b = [-4, 5, -6]
coincidence = 0
#Идём по графику
x = 0
while x < len(a):
    if b[x] == a[x]: #Жалуется на эту строку    
        coincidence += 1
    else:
        coincidence = 0
    if coincidence == len(b):
        print('Элемент найден!')
    x += 1

Вот код, он жалуется на строку 7, не понимаю в чём проблема, два списка есть, переменная счётчик есть. В чём проблема? Мне конечно не так важен этот кусок кода задрипаный, но у меня аж глаз задёргался от него.

Когда x равен 3, какое значение имеет b[x]?

Всё я понял XD, пойду отдохну наверное.

Вообще, кажется, если просто заменить b[x] на b[coincidence], то код станет работать как надо (если я правильно понял его смысл)
